# Pyarrow.flight.do_get segfault when pandas Dataframe over 3GB

Tags: python, pyarrow

I have two dataframes in my flight server: v1 and v2. V1 is quite small and v2 is a around 3gb. I can ask the server for v1 successfully but when asking for v2 a segfault occurs.

```
import numpy.random as rnd
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.flight as fl
import numpy as np


class MyFlightServer(FlightServerBase):
    def __init__(self, location=None, options=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(location, **kwargs)
        self.tables = {}
        rng = rnd.default_rng()
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.standard_normal((1000, 5))).rename(
            columns={k: "col" + str(k) for k in range(5)}
        )
        self.tables[b"v1"] = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

        df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.standard_normal((100000000, 5))).rename(
            columns={k: "col" + str(k) for k in range(5)}
        )
        print(df2.info())
        self.tables[b"v2"] = pa.Table.from_pandas(df2)

    def do_get(self, context, ticket):
        return RecordBatchStream(self.tables[ticket.ticket])


def main():
    with MyFlightServer() as server:
        # This works
        client = fl.connect(("localhost", server.port))
        data = client.do_get(fl.Ticket("v1")).read_pandas()

        # This will get a seg fault
        data = client.do_get(fl.Ticket("v2")).read_pandas()


main()
```

The above produces the below output (maybe relevant for df details):

```
RangeIndex: 100000000 entries, 0 to 99999999
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column  Dtype  
---  ------  -----  
 0   col0    float64
 1   col1    float64
 2   col2    float64
 3   col3    float64
 4   col4    float64
dtypes: float64(5)
memory usage: 3.7 GB
None
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The machine this is running on has 64GB RAM of which around 15GB are in use at the time of running. Therefore I'm discounting (perhaps naively) the possibility of it not finding a continuous block of memory.

Am I misusing the flight server/record batch streamer or could this be a bug?

versions involved:

```
numpy==1.21.0
pandas==1.2.5
pyarrow==4.0.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
six==1.16.0

Python 3.9.5 (default, May 19 2021, 11:32:47) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
```

Comment: I can reproduce this. Thank you for the reproduction. I'll do some more investigating; likely this will end up with filing a bug on [Arrow's JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARROW/issues) (which you are also free to do; if you wish to do so, please tag lidavidm there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Arrow Flight. See [ARROW-13253](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-13253) for details. Essentially, it's because the Flight handler sends the data as a single RecordBatch, but right now, Flight does not support sending record batches > 2GiB in size. However, the internal serialization handler returns an error without initializing the output buffer, which gRPC tries to blindly manipulate without checking for an error, leading to a crash.

You can work around this by explicitly chunking the data:

```
def do_get(self, context, ticket):
    table = self.tables[ticket.ticket]
    batches = table.to_batches(max_chunksize=65536)
    return fl.GeneratorStream(table.schema, batches)
```